# checking dll registration in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, dll

How can I see which dlls are registered in my Windows 7 machine? I registered a dll, but am still unsure if it's really registered and want to check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sysinternals has [ListDLLs](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896656.aspx) that will list all loaded DLLs.

Comment: ListDLLs give the list of currently used (loaded) DLL, not the registried ones.

Answer (score 1):

using the find command in regedit search [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\SharedDLLs].

Answer (score 1):

This did it for me

```
REG QUERY HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\AppID\<dllname>
```

Or

```
REG QUERY HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\AppID\<dllname>
```

Comment: Can you expand you answer with how/where to do this?

Comment: @fixer1234 It seems to be something you can run through the normal Windows console.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [RegDllView from Nirsoft.net](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/registered_dll_view.html)(x64 and x32), take in account that there are *two registers places* depending of your library is x32 or x64.

[image]